# Function: receive multiple inputs, and add those to a column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a newbie writing google sheets functions.
I'd like to achieve the following:
Every time a value is inserted in a prompt window,
the value should be copied in the C column, in the first empty cell.

This function should repeat until the user will manually close the prompt window.

```
    function inserisciID()
{
 // Chiede il valore (asks for value)
 var ID =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Spara l'ID prodotto").getResponseText();
 //Inserisce l'ID nella prima cella vuota della colonna A 
//(finds a blank cell, but I don't know how to find it in the C column)
 var blank = dealCells.join().split(',');

for(var i = 0; i > 0; i++)
 {
    if (blank.indexOf("") != -1)  {
     cell.setValue(ID);
     i==-1;
  }
// I missed the 'else'
 }  
}
```

Comment: `This function should repeat until the user will manually close the prompt window.` this does not make sense. Can you explain more what you need? The first line in your code creates a prompt input field. If you want the rest of the code to be executed, you need to press ok and therefore close the prompt window. Do you maybe mean, add comma seperated values in the input field and then paste them to column C?

Comment: @Marios Thanks for the feedback. Yes, it wll be ok to separate values by comma. I'll explain briefly: the user will input the value in the prompt input field via a barcode scanner, and will repeat the input for multiple barcodes (it would be great to achieve that without manually inserting commas, but it's ok if he has to). Then those values should be pasted in the C column (in the first empty cell). Thank you very much!

Comment: check if my answer worked for you. About that `those values should be pasted in the C column (in the first empty cell)` you want all the values into one cell, or each value into a different cell?

Comment: @Marios In separate cells, in the column C. I'm checking, thankyou!

Comment: @Marios Thanks man, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

I think your goal is to input a set of comma seperated values and append each of these values to column C after the last cell with content.

- You don't need a for loop to achieve that. As soon as the user inputs a list of comma separated values: `test1,test1`. You [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) these values by comma and you create the desired array. Since your goal is to append the data into a single column, you need to convert this 1D array to a 2D array of the form: `[ [test1], [test2],..]`. To do that, you can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

  ```
  const input = ID.split(',').map(r=>[r]);
  ```
- After you have calculated the `input` array, you need to find the last cell with content of column C. To do that you can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

  ```
  const start_row=sheet.getRange('C:C').getValues().filter(String).length + 1;
  ```
- Finally, you can efficiently set all the values to column C by using [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues):

  ```
  sheet.getRange(start_row,3,input.length,1).setValues(input);
  ```

### Solution:

```
function inserisciID(){
 const ID =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Spara l'ID prodotto").getResponseText();
 const input = ID.split(',').map(r=>[r]);
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
 const start_row=sheet.getRange('C:C').getValues().filter(String).length + 1;
 sheet.getRange(start_row,3,input.length,1).setValues(input);
}
```

As I mentioned in the explanation section, the input values by the user need to be separated by comma: `test1,test2,test3` etc.